# Ordering on ultrapower of $\mathbb{Q} $

Tags: order-theory, first-order-logic

Prove that the ordering on the real number is not isomorphic to an ultrapower of the ordering of the rationals. Hint: an ultrapower of $\mathbb{Q} $ is not complete.

I cannot understand the hint; I mean, $\mathbb{Q} $ is an elementary substructure of $\mathbb{R}$ and then they should be elementary equivalent, then the completeness shouldn't be first order aziomatizable. 
Moreover by Los's theorem and ultrapower of $\mathbb{Q} $ should be elementary equivalent to $\mathbb{Q} $. 
Hence the only way I can see to prove the statement is by mean of cardinality, but in this case the hint wouldn't help me at all. 
Where am I wrong?

Comment: I think you are being asked to prove that the ultrapower of $\Bbb{Q}$ is not complete. Isn't the image of a set like $\{x : x^2 < 2\}$ in the ultrapower a set that is bounded above but has no least upper bound?

Comment: Ok, i have to think about what happens in ultrapower of Q with the set you pointed out, since I cannot apply Los theorem in this case. Moreover the isomorphism we would consider in this case is of second order structures, ain't it?

Comment: Just use the definition of the ultrapower.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed true that as ordered sets, any ultrapower of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are elementarily equivalent.

However, any ultrapower of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be given an ordered field structure in which the sentence $\forall x\lnot (x\cdot x=1+1)$ is true. But the reals as an ordered set cannot be given such a field structure.

Comment: Your example is very clear, but the only way I know to give such a structure of field to these sets starts from Peano arithmetic. Is there any better or quicker way to do it? Maybe I can start from the usual structure of field, show it defines the natural order on R and Q and use it to prove the statement. Is it right?

Comment: We are proving the result about non-isomorphism  using ordinary mathematical reasoning. It is a standard theorem, proved in many analysis courses, that the reals are, up to isomorphism, the only ordered field in which the ordering is order-complete.  Peano arithmetic is not relevant to the proof. The proof can be carried out in a formal set theory, if we really wish to do so.  But it is important to remember that the tools we use to prove theorems of Model Theory are the same tools that we use in studying PDE, or any other branch  of mathematics.